# Access 2010 - Connecting LocalDB to Microsoft Access via DSN

Tags: sql, ms-access, localdb

I have created a local db and I want to connect some tables to Microsoft Access. I'm doing this via Microsoft Access's "Link to the data source by creating a linked table" feature" and in order to do that I need to create a DSN. However I'm getting an error where it says

> "Server does not exist or access denied"

[image]

At the moment I'm trying to create a new DSN and i'm stuck during the below step which I need to specify my server. I've tried two different server names and they both don't work.

Note: It's definitely not an access denied issue because I've tested the login myself and they all work fine.
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or is it not possible to link Access to a local db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a LocalDB I used SQLExpress which worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

### Resolution

When choosing a driver for the new data source, use either the ***ODBC Driver...for SQL Server*** or the ***SQL Server Native Client***.  *(note: I am also able to get the "SQL Server" driver to work, but only by specifying the named pipe address of the instance in the next step/image where specifying the SQL Server to connect to.)*

[image]

The SQL Server to connect to in the "Create a New Data Source to SQL Server" should be **"(LocalDB)\*instancename*"**; in this case **"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB"**

[image]

---

### Caveats

- As the LocalDB name itself implies, connections to it can only be
  made from the local machine.  If you need to access an instance on a
  different machine, and need a free solution, you should use SQL
  Server Express.
- These results were obtained using Access 2016. My
  experience with other software indicates it should work with Access
  2010 as well, but I did not test that. If you have trouble, try using
  the named pipe address for the instance instead of the
  "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" moniker in the image above.

---

### Results

Here are the results of testing the connection, then adding links to two tables in the master database

[image]

[image]

[image]